# Unable to load asset (image) in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

[This is how the code (app) looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM2AE.png)

Aight people this is my first time doing this so I'll try to be precise and neat...

So I've just started learning flutter and I am watching a course on it, but while copying what the instructor was typing I stumbled upon on this problem whenever I try to run this code on my virtual or physical device it doesn't load the image. I've checked pubsec.yaml file and everything seems to be working fine but the image doesn't load. Btw I'm using AndroidStudio the latest version (canary I guess). Thanks in advance I hope someone kind will help me. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text('I am rich.'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('diamond.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here is a download link for the image in the code:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1IA7othwL6jGtvc1Wfyj0K6hxrEH9OHam

Comment: did you place the `diamond.png` in the *root folder* of your project? You have to specify the path from the root of your project to that file. The same you have listed in your `pubspec.yaml` (also make sure you stop and completely restart the app, resources changes will not be reflected with hot reload or hot restart)

Comment: Could you please show us the pubspec.yaml as well ? And where did you put the image?

Answer (score 0):

When you have local files that you want to use within your code, you need to remember to **add it into the pubspec.yaml** file under the assets section. Here is an example of me registering a couple images over there:

```
flutter:
  ...
  assets:
    - diamond.png
    - gemstones/emerald.jpg
```

Please note that files (and folders) containing **assets you wish to use should be registered in the root folder of your app** and not your lib folder.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure what happened but creating a new project and changing the folder's name worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the path of your image in the `pubspec.yaml`?
For the Flutter to recognizes your asset image, you need to put the path of him in the `pubspec.yaml` file of your project.